# Return error as a JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

The question is simple: return an error from a controller as JSON response:

```ruby
//controller
def action1
   # .....
   return render(json: { status: :unprocessable_entity }) if !is_my_valid?
   # .... doing something
   render(json: my_hash.to_json)  

end
```

```javascript
//view
$.ajax({
  url: 'some_url',
  //...
}).done(function(data) {
  // it always gets here even in case of an error

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert("error: " + textStatus);
});
```

So the problem is that on the HTML page, even in case of an error, the callback function in `.done()` is executed, not the one in `.fail()`. How do I make it into `.fail()`?

Comment: The AJAX request succeeds, thus your for `.done()` callback is executed.

Comment: @NabilKadimi, the sky is blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send back a 500 HTTP status code:

```
render(json: { ... }, status: 500)
```

Comment: well, it's working, how do I also send the error message so it'll be shown in `fail` by alert?

Comment: @Grienders You would have to add that error message to the JSON, and then retrieve it inside the `.fail()`.

Comment: `}).fail(function(data) { alert("error: " + data.responseText + " status: " + data.status); });` -- this will show error message and status of error.